# i'm trying to run the default flutter app but i get an error

Tags: flutter

**i've installed the latest flutter version and trying to run the default app coming with it but i get this error**

[image]

**this is my environment variables paths**

[image]

i've checked if flutter has installed correctly and here's the result

[image]

Comment: run `flutter doctor -v` to see more details on your doctor errors

Answer (score 0):

It's a connection error, you should have a fast internet connection. also, install the dart plugin in android studio

Comment: thank you for your response , dart plugin is already installed and my internet connection is fast and stable but i still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
flutter channel beta
flutter clean
flutter run
```

and it works , the problem has been solved